# transponer columnas a filas usando pivot no me funciono

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

tengo algo así:

| SEMANA | ANIO | Nombre | dias_de_trabajo | variable_1 | variable_2 | variable_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | aranza | 4 | 134 | 34 | 131 |
| 2 | 2019 | juana | 5 | 2423 | 23 | 141 |
| 3 | 2019 | fer | 7 | 242 | 56 | 1341 |
| 4 | 2019 | Juan | 2 | 2442 | 35 | 1341 |

y quiero transponerla, ya intente usar pivot table pero lo que busco es llegar a esto:

| SEMANA | ANIO | Nombre | dias_de_trabajo | VARIABLE | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | aranza | 4 | variable_1 | 134 |
| 1 | 2019 | aranza | 4 | variable_2 | 34 |
| 1 | 2019 | aranza | 4 | variable_3 | 131 |
| 1 | 2019 | juana | 5 | variable_1 | 2423 |
| 1 | 2019 | juana | 5 | variable_2 | 23 |
| 1 | 2019 | juana | 5 | variable_3 | 14 |

que queden los valores asi , alguna idea?

Comment: Adicione el código que ha intentado

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.SEMANA,
       a.ANIO,
       a.NOMBRE,
       'variable1' as variable,
       a.VARIABLE1 as valor
from bitacora a
union
select a.SEMANA,
       a.ANIO,
       a.NOMBRE,
       'variable2' as variable,
       a.VARIABLE2 as valor
from bitacora a
union
select a.SEMANA,
       a.ANIO,
       a.NOMBRE,
       'variable3' as variable,
       a.VARIABLE3 as valor
from bitacora a
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

Y el resultado es:

```
SEMANA ANIO NOMBRE VARIABLE  VALOR
     1 2019 aranza variable1   134
     1 2019 aranza variable2    34
     1 2019 aranza variable3   131
     2 2019 juana  variable1  2423
     2 2019 juana  variable2    23
     2 2019 juana  variable3   141
     3 2019 fer    variable1   242
     3 2019 fer    variable2    56
     3 2019 fer    variable3  1341
     4 2019 Juan   variable1  2442
     4 2019 Juan   variable2    35
     4 2019 Juan   variable3  1341
```